# how to validate dynamic created element in jquery without using plugin

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

here i have created dynamic elements after clicking its adding one row.but how to validate it without plugin.

```
var cnt = 1;
$("#anc_add").click(function() {
    cnt++;
    $("input[id=rows]").val(cnt);
    $('#tbl1 tr').last().after('<tr><td><select name="'+cnt+'1" id="'+cnt+'1" class="Exp"><option value="0" >Select Expenses Type</option></select></td><td><textarea name="'+cnt+'2"></textarea></td><td><input type="text" name="'+cnt+'3" id="'+cnt+'3"  onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)"></td></tr>');  
    element_id=cnt+'1';/*alert(element_id);*/
    $.ajax({
        url: "../../modal/system_operator/get_companyexpenses_type.php",
        dataType: "html",
        type: 'POST',
        success:function(json) {
            var result = jQuery.parseJSON(json);
            length=result.len;
            /*alert(length);*/
            for(k=1;k<=length;k++) {
                $('#'+element_id+' option').last().after('<option value="'+eval("result.row"+k+".company_expenses_type_id")+'">'+eval("result.row"+k+".company_expenses_type")+'</option>');
            }
            $('select[name="'+element_id+'"]').rules('add', {required:true});
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume by without plugin means you do not use jquery.validate or some other plugin to validate your input control values.

Then try the following snippet

```
$(document).on('blur','#form_id input,#form_id select', function(){
   // write your validation logic here
});
```

The above code says that all (including dynamic) input,select controls within #form_id element will call the function on blur event.